# Stack Overflow talent for English (UK) links to US developer hiring library page

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-talent

1. Go to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent and choose English (UK) as your language preference so you then end up at https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/uk/talent (you could just go to the UK page directly if you wanted to I believe)
2. Scroll down to the Developer Hiring Library image at the bottom right of the page
3. Click on it and you're taken to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/careers/us/recruiting-guides which then warns you that the language has changed and offers to correct it.

Desired result:

The UK talent page should link directly to the UK recruiting guide

Note that in German this bug is not present. You are taken directly to the German recruiting guide from the German talent page.